# Firefox 78: change bookmark bar color in userChrome.css

Tags: colors, firefox

I have this in my `userChrome.css`:

```
#main-window #PersonalToolbar {
    background-color: green !important;
    color: white !important;
}
```

After upgrade from Firefox 68.x to 78.3, this no longer has any effect, and my bookmark bar is grey. How can I change it to green, as I had done for version 68 ?

Comment: try toggling `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` in `about:config`. Though that option may be gone for good, unfortunately

Comment: @user414777 - `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` was alredy set to `true`.

Comment: Then you can forget about it. Sorry. I suspect that he chances that they would reimplement it in firefox 7x (which is completely re-engineered) are near 0.

Comment: Please ask here as well: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewforum.php?f=8